# "ADB device" conflicto con "TNS device"

Tags: nativescript, adb

Tengo un problema que la verdad, me esta rompiendo la cabeza mucho....

Estoy intentando instalar una aplicacion con NativeScript en un Android(Xiaomi Mi Max 3). Pero al intentar hacer el `tns run android` me dice que no ha encontrado dispositivos.

En ese momento, activo mi depuracion USB, le doy a confiar en mi ordenador y vuelvo a probar. ME DA EL MISMO ERROR, no reconoce nada el comando `tns devices`, sin embargo el comando `adb devices` SI ME LO RECONOCE ¡

Es algo frustrante porque cuando no le doy a "Confiar en mi ordenador" el comando `tns devices` me detecta mi Android pero de esta manera:

```
┌───┬─────────────┬──────────┬───────────────────┬────────┬─────────────┐
│ # │ Device Name │ Platform │ Device Identifier │ Type   │ Status      │
│ 1 │             │ Android  │ 9ca3acaf          │ Device │ Unreachable │
```

En el momento en que "confio" y le doy acceso, el comando `tns devices` no detecta nada. Asi queda:

```
Connected devices & emulators
Searching for devices...
Cannot find connected devices. Reconnect any connected devices, verify that your system recognizes them, and run this command again.
```

Y si hago el comando `adb devices` :

```
List of devices attached
9ca3acaf        device
```

No se que hacer ya... quizá sea por mi ROM que es personalizada es una ROM europea de xioami, pero no debería.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: por favor ... alguien ? realmente es urgente...